# Left Linear Grammar: How to construct?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, formal-grammars

I need help constructing a Left Linear grammar for the language

$L = \{ a^n b^m c^p \mid n\geq 2, m\geq 3, p\geq 4 \}$

Here is what I have so far, I know :

$N = \{S\}$

$T = \{ a, b, c \}$

$P = \{$

$S \rightarrow Pcccc$

$P \rightarrow Pc$

$P \rightarrow M$

$M \rightarrow Mbbb$

$M \rightarrow Mb$

$M \rightarrow N$

$N \rightarrow Naa$

$N\rightarrow a$

$\}$

I need help figuring out the productions. I am not sure if I am doing it right.

Comment: Since you can't do the exercise yourself, it's obvious that there's something you've not understood. However, giving you a solution to this particular exercise very probably won't help you understand that thing, which doesn't really help you. Can you try to describe what more precisely what it is that you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 3):

In the strictest sense, productions of the form $X \rightarrow Y\alpha\beta\gamma\ldots$ (i.e. where there's more than one terminal) are not allowed, so if you want to be particularly formal, you would need to change the productions like $S\rightarrow Pcccc$ to a series of productions that do things step by step, e.g.

$S\rightarrow P_{1}c$,
$P_{1}\rightarrow P_{2}c$,
$P_{2} \rightarrow P_{3}c\ldots$.

This is may not appear to be a serious problem, however there are mistakes in your grammar, for example it generates the string $acccc$ via the derivation $S\Rightarrow Pcccc \Rightarrow Mcccc \Rightarrow Ncccc \Rightarrow acccc$. Interestingly by fixing the transitions with multiple terminals, you fix this problem.

So for example, a small part of the change could (there are many possible correct grammars) be:

$S\rightarrow Pcccc$
$P\rightarrow Pc \mid Mbbb$

Importantly the $P\rightarrow M$ transition should be removed, it's what is allowing the jump past the $b$s, the key part of the change is forcing the first group of characters when you move from one nonterminal to the next.

There's also a small error where the grammar only allows 3 $a$s, but that's most likely a typo or close enough to one that it should be obvious how to fix it.

On a more general note, if you are comfortable with DFAs, you can treat both right and left linear grammars (but not unqualified linear grammars, has to be either right or left) in much the same way as a DFA, just thing of the nonterminals as the states, and the productions as the transitions - the terminal is the label on the transition and the nonterminal is the new state. The significant difference is that you don't need a production that deals with every terminal - grammars only deal with strings that are in the language, whereas automata have to deal with input that isn't in the language  (and reject it).